# How to mock TS class in unit tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import {Calendar} from '@fullcalendar/core';

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.calendar = new Calendar(this.element.nativeElement, config);
  this.calendar.render();
}
```

I'm using fullcalendar plugin but it has nothing to do with my original question, I think, it might be any other dependency. So the plugin creates a calendar view. It is up to fullcalendar team to test the calendar behavior, while I'm responsible to test the calendar integration. So I need to test that the calendar has been initialized with correct config, therefore I want to omit real constructor and retrieve params. And also I don't want to create an instance of the calendar.

How to mock `Calendar` class in my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to wrap your library calls. First of all it's easier to test them and if the library interface will change you only have to change your code at a single location and keep your own interface in the rest of your code.

Therefore one solution for your problem would be to wrap the calendar creation in a factory service like:

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class FullcalendarFactoryService{

  public buildCalendar(element:HTMLElement,config:any){
    return new Calendar(element,config);
  }
}
```

In your component you have to inject your factory service and use it like:

```
constructor(public calenderFactory:FullcalendarFactoryService) {
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.calendar = this.calenderFactory.buildCalendar(this.element.nativeElement,this.config);
    this.calendar.render();
}
```

And to test, you could simply mock your factory function like shown below:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        YourComponent
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: FullcalendarFactoryService,
        useClass: class {
          buildCalendar = jasmine.createSpy('buildCalendar').and.returnValue({
            render: () => true
          });
        }
      }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    calendarFactory = TestBed.get(FullcalendarFactoryService);

}));

it('should call factory method with element and config', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(calendarFactory.buildCalendar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fixture.componentInstance.element.nativeElement, fixture.componentInstance.config);
  });
```

### UPDATE:

To test if the services `buildCalendar` function returns an instance of `Calendar` you would test your service like shown below:

```
import {FullcalendarFactoryService} from './fullcalendar-factory.service';
import {Calendar} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'

describe('calendar factory service', () => {
  let factory:FullcalendarFactoryService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    factory = new FullcalendarFactoryService();
  })

  it('should return calender instance',() => {
    expect(factory.buildCalendar(document.createElement('test'),{plugins:[dayGridPlugin]})).toEqual(jasmine.any(Calendar))
  })
})
```

Comment: Good point, but how do you test that `buildCalendar` method of `FullcalendarFactoryService` returns Calendar object? This part is still uncovered. Now I can test arguments, but it does not test that `buildCalendar` returns Calendar instance instead of undefined.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to do this.